# Función que recibe dos punteros a funciones y devuelve otro - C

Tags: c, punteros

Quiero escribir una función que reciba dos punteros a funciones y devuelva un puntero a la función `composicion`. ¿Es posible hacer eso?

Esta era mi idea:

```
typedef int (*funcionEntera) (int);

funcionEntera composicion(funcionEntera f1, funcionEntera f2) {
    return f1(f2);
}
```

Comment: `return f1;` sin llamarla?

Comment: Pero eso devuelve la f1. Yo quiero construir una nueva funcion que sea f1 evaluada en f2.

Comment: En tiempo de ejecución ningún lenguaje te permite crear nuevas funciones, a menos que estes haciendo reflection. Javascript es una excepcion.

Comment: Puedes devolver un struct que almacene los dos punteros y luego pasarlo a un método que ejecute las dos funciones, una detrás de la otra. Pero no crear una función completamente nueva.

Comment: No creo que se pueda, tal como indicaron otros.

Comment: ¿Necesitas hacerlo por algún motivo en particular o es una duda existencial? En particular `return f1(f2);` es una llamada imposible porque el parámetro que pide `f1` sería de tipo entero y no puntero a función.

Comment: @DamianAriel Solo conozco una forma de hacerlo: usando [FFCALL](https://www.haible.de/bruno/packages-ffcall.html). Échale un ojo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay dos fallos de concepto. El primero ya te lo ha comentado @JoséManuelRamos. Así que no voy a hacer más comentarios al respecto.

El segundo es que estás pretendiendo que la función te devuelva un puntero a una función configurada con `f2(n)`... algo que no es posible... al menos en C.

Sí podrías, por ejemplo, tener una función que en función de los parámetros de entrada, decidiese que debes llamar a una función u otra:

```
funcionEntera elegirFuncion(funcionEntera f1, funcionEntera f2, int param)
{
  if( param )
    return f1;
  else
    return f2;
}
```

También podrías, por ejemplo, ejecutar la función correspondiente a nivel interno y devolver el resultado. Nota que en este caso el tipo de retorno de la función no es un puntero a función

```
int elegirFuncion(funcionEntera f1 , funcionEntera f2, int n)
{
  if( n % 2 )
    return f1(n);
  else
    return f2(n);
}
```

Y a partir de estos dos casos, cualquier combinación lineal de los mismos. Pero no, en C no existe un mecanismo que te permita devolver un puntero a una función ya *configurada*... para eso te quedas con el valor de retorno de la función y lo devuelves... que viene a ser lo mismo pero más sencillo:

```
typedef int (*funcionEntera) (int);

int composicion(funcionEntera f1, funcionEntera f2, int n) {
    return f1(f2(n));
}
```

Ahora bien, si tu idea es ir compononiendo una ecuación compleja sobre la marcha, lo que tienes que hacer es recurrir a las estructuras. El diseño es algo más complejo pero te permite configurar la secuencia de operaciones sobre la marcha:

```
typedef int (*funcionEntera) (int);

struct NodoFunc
{
  funcionEntera f;
  struct NodoFunc* siguiente;
};

struct Operacion
{
  struct NodoFunc* primera;
};

struct Operacion NuevaOperacion()
{
  struct Operacion op;
  op.primera = 0;

  return op;
}

void NuevaFuncion(struct Operacion* op, funcionEntera func)
{
  struct NodoFunc* nuevoNodo = (struct NodoFunc*)calloc(1,sizeof(struct NodoFunc));
  nuevoNodo->f = func;

  if( op->primera == 0 )
    op->primera = nuevoNodo;
  else
  {
    struct NodoFunc* nodo = op->primera;
    while( nodo->siguiente ) nodo = nodo->siguiente;

    nodo->siguiente = nuevoNodo;
  }
}

int Ejecutar(struct Operacion op, int n)
{
  int toReturn = 0;

  if( op.primera )
  {
    toReturn = n;
    struct NodoFunc* nodo = op.primera;
    while( nodo )
    {
      toReturn = nodo->f(toReturn);
      nodo = nodo->siguiente;
    }
  }

  return toReturn;
}

void LiberarMemoria(struct Operacion* op)
{
  struct NodoFunc* nodo = op->primera;
  op->primera = 0;

  while( nodo )
  {
    struct NodoFunc* sig = nodo->siguiente;
    free(nodo);
    nodo = sig;
  }
}

int Inc(int n)
{
  return n+1;
}

int Add5(int n)
{
  return n+5;
}

int FiltroPar(int n)
{
  return n%2? 0 : n;
}

int main()
{
  struct Operacion op = NuevaOperacion();

  NuevaFuncion(&op,Inc);
  NuevaFuncion(&op,Inc);

  printf("%d\n",Ejecutar(op,0)); // 2 = 0 + 1 + 1

  NuevaFuncion(&op,Add5);
  printf("%d\n",Ejecutar(op,0)); // 7 = 0 + 1 + 1 + 5

  NuevaFuncion(&op,FiltroPar);
  NuevaFuncion(&op,Inc);

  printf("%d\n",Ejecutar(op,0)); // 1 = 0 ( 0 + 1 + 1 + 5 = 7, no es divisible entre 2 ) + 1
  printf("%d\n",Ejecutar(op,1)); // 9 = 8 ( 1 + 1 + 1 + 5 = 8, es divisible entre 2) + 1

  LiberarMemoria(&op);
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: Haz un interprete :P; muy buena respuesta!

Comment: gracias @NaCl :)

Answer (score 1):

Hay un error en lo que quieres realizar, y consiste en que quieres hacer

```
f1(f2)
```

Pero declaras `f1` como función y a `f2` como función también. ¿No tendrías que declarar a `f2` como entero? ¿O es que quieres realizar `f1(f2(n))` con n el número entero que quieres utilizar?

En cualquier caso, estoy dando por supuesto que las funciones que quieres llamar están previamente declaradas e implementadas, y que esta función tan sólo las utiliza en una llamada.

Un saludo.